# nth smallest element in a union of an array of intervals with repetition

Tags: algorithm, methods

I want to know if there is a more efficient solution than what I came up with(not coded it yet but described the gist of it at the bottom).

Write a function calcNthSmallest(n, intervals) which takes as input a non-negative int n, and a list of intervals [[a_1; b_1]; : : : ; [a_m; b_m]] and calculates the nth smallest number (0-indexed) when taking the union of all the intervals with repetition. For example, if the intervals were [1; 5]; [2; 4]; [7; 9], their union with repetition would be [1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 4; 5; 7; 8; 9] (note 2; 3; 4 each appear twice since they're in both the intervals [1; 5] and [2; 4]). For this list of intervals, the 0th smallest number would be 1, and the 3rd and 4th smallest would both be 3. Your implementation should run quickly even when the a_i; b_i can be very large (like, one trillion), and there are several intervals

The way I thought to go about it is the straightforward solution which is to make the union array and traverse it.

Comment: What have you tried?? Where are you getting an error?? We won't do your homework.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore This is not my homework and I wouldn't want YOU to do it if it were :P I am not getting an error. Just wanted to know if there is a better way than I thought

Comment: No offence meant bro, if you say "if there is a better way than I thought" then you have to let us know WHAT you thought, forget the homework part but you must specify what you already tried or you have in mind.

Comment: now that it makes much more sense, thinking of an optimum solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved in O(N log N) where N is the number of intervals in the list, regardless of the actual values of the interval endpoints.

The key to solving this problem efficiently is to transform the list of possibly-overlapping intervals into a list of intervals which are either disjoint or identical. In the given example, only the first interval needs to be split:

```
{       [1,5],        [2,4], [7,9]} =>
 +-----------------+  +---+  +---+
{[1,1], [2,4], [5,5], [2,4], [7,9]}
```

(This doesn't have to be done explicitly, though: see below.) Now, we can sort the new intervals, replacing duplicates with a count. From that, we can compute the number of values each (possibly-duplicated) interval represents. Now, we simply need to accumulate the values to figure out which interval the solution lies in:

```
interval  count  size    values     cumulative
                       in interval    values
  [1,1]     1      1        1         [0, 1)
  [2,4]     2      3        6         [1, 7)  (eg. from n=1 to n=6 will be here)
  [5,5]     1      1        1         [7, 8)
  [7,9]     1      3        3         [8, 11)
```

I wrote the cumulative values as a list of half-open intervals, but obviously we only need the end-points. We can then find which interval holds value n by, for example, binary-searching the cumulative values list, and we can figure out which value in the interval we want by subtracting the start of the interval from n and then integer-dividing by the count.

It should be clear that the maximum size of the above table is twice the number of original intervals, because every row must start and end at either the start or end of some interval in the original list. If we'd written the intervals as half-open instead of closed, this would be even clearer; in that case, we can assert that the precise size of the table will be the number of unique values in the collection of end-points. And from that insight, we can see that we don't really need the table at all; we just need the sorted list of end-points (although we need to know which endpoint each value represents). We can simply iterate through that list, maintaining the count of the number of active intervals, until we reach the value we're looking for.

Here's a quick python implementation. It could be improved.

```
def combineIntervals(intervals):
  # endpoints will map each endpoint to a count
  endpoints = {}
  # These two lists represent the start and (1+end) of each interval
  # Each start adds 1 to the count, and each limit subtracts 1
  for start in (i[0] for i in intervals):
    endpoints[start] = endpoints.setdefault(start, 0) + 1
  for limit in (i[1]+1 for i in intervals):
    endpoints[limit] = endpoints.setdefault(limit, 0) - 1
  # Filtering is a possibly premature optimization but it was easy
  return sorted(filter(lambda kv: kv[1] != 0,
                       endpoints.iteritems()))

def nthSmallestInIntervalList(n, intervals):
  limits = combineIntervals(intervals)
  cumulative = 0
  count = 0
  index = 0
  here = limits[0][0]
  while index < len(limits):
    size = limits[index][0] - here
    if n < cumulative + count * size:
      # [here, next) contains the value we're searching for
      return here + (n - cumulative) / count
    # advance
    cumulative += count * size
    count += limits[index][1]
    here += size
    index += 1
  # We didn't find it. We could throw an error
```

So, as I said, the running time of this algorithm is independent of the actual values of the intervals; it only depends in the length of the interval list. This particular solution is `O(N log N)` because of the cost of the sort (in `combineIntervals`); if we used a priority queue instead of a full sort, we could construct the heap in `O(N)` but making the scan `O(log N)` for each scanned endpoint. Unless `N` is really big and the expected value of the argument `n` is relatively small, this would be counter-productive. There might be other ways to reduce complexity, though.

Answer (score 2):

Edit2:

Here's yet another take on your question.

Let's consider the intervals graphically:

```
             1  1   1 2  2  2  3
   0-2-4--7--0--3---7-0--4--7--0
     [-------]
       [-----------------]
          [---------]
                [--------------]
                      [-----]
```

When sorted in increasing order on the lower bound, we could get something that looks like the above for the interval list `([2;10];[4;24];[7;17];[13;30];[20;27])`. Each lower bound indicates the start of a new interval, and would also marks the beginning of one more "level" of duplication of the numbers. Conversely, upper bounds mark the end of that level, and decrease the duplication level of one. 
We could therefore convert the above into the following list:

```
   [2;+];[4;+];[7;+][10;-];[13;+];[17;-][20;+];[24;-];[27;-];[30;-]
```

Where the first value indicates the rank of the bound, and the second value whether the bound is lower (`+`) or upper (`-`). The computation of the nth element is done by following the list, raising or lowering the duplication level when encountering an lower or upper bound, and using the duplication level as a counting factor.

Let's consider again the list graphically, but as an histogram:

```
          3333  44444 5555
       2222222333333344444555
     111111111222222222222444444
             1  1   1 2  2  2  3
   0-2-4--7--0--3---7-0--4--7--0
```

The view above is the same as the first one, with all the intervals packed vertically.
`1` being the elements of the 1st one, `2` the second one, etc. In fact, what matters here
is the height at each index, corresponding of the number of time each index is duplicated in the union of all intervals.

```
          3333  55555 7777
       2223333445555567777888
     112223333445555567777888999
             1  1   1 2  2  2  3
   0-2-4--7--0--3---7-0--4--7--0
   | | |  |   | |    ||   |  |
```

We can see that histogram blocks start at lower bounds of intervals, and end either on upper bounds, or one unit before lower bounds, so the new notation must be modified accordingly.

With a list containing *n* intervals, as a first step, we convert the list into the notation above (*O(n)*), and sort it in increasing bound order (*O(nlog(n))*). The second step of computing the number is then in *O(n)*, for a total average time in *O(nlog(n)*).

Here's a simple implementation in OCaml, using `1` and `-1` instead of '+' and '-'.

```
(* transform the list in the correct notation *)
let rec convert = function
      [] -> []
    | (l,u)::xs -> (l,1)::(u+1,-1)::convert xs;;

(* the counting function *)
let rec count r f = function
      [] -> raise Not_found
    | [a,x] -> (match f + x with 
          0 -> if r = 0 then a else raise Not_found
                    | _ -> a + (r / f))
    | (a,x)::(b,y)::l ->
         if a = b
         then count r f ((b,x+y)::l)
         else
             let f = f + x in
             if f > 0 then
                 let range = (b - a) * f in
                 if range > r
                 then a + (r / f)
                 else count (r - range) f ((b,y)::l)
             else count r f ((b,y)::l);;

(* the compute function *)
let compute l = 
    let compare (x,_) (y,_) = compare x y in
    let l = List.sort compare (convert l) in
    fun m -> count m 0 l;;
```

Notes: 
- the function above will raise an exception if the sought number is above the intervals. This corner case isn't taken in account by the other methods below.
- the list sorting function used in OCaml is merge sort, which effectively performs in *O(nlog(n))*.

---

Edit:

Seeing that you might have very large intervals, the solution I gave initially (see down below) is far from optimal.
Instead, we could make things much faster by transforming the list: 
we try to compress the interval list by searching for overlapping ones and replace them by prefixing intervals, several times the overlapping one, and suffixing intervals. We can then directly compute the number of entries covered by each element of the list. 
Looking at the splitting above (prefix, infix, suffix), we see that the optimal structure to do the processing is a binary tree. A node of that tree may optionally have a prefix and a suffix. So the node must contain :

- an interval `i` in the node
- an integer giving the number of repetition of `i` in the list,
- a left subtree of all the intervals below `i`
- a right subtree of all the intervals above `i`

with this structure in place, the tree is automatically sorted.
Here's an example of an ocaml type embodying that tree.

```
type tree = Empty | Node of int * interval * tree * tree
```

Now the transformation algorithm boils down to building the tree.

This function create a tree out of its component:

```
let cons k r lt rt = 
   the tree made of count k, interval r, left tree lt and right tree rt
```

This function recursively insert an interval in a tree.

```
let rec insert i it =
   let r = root of it
   let lt = the left subtree of it
   let rt = the right subtree of it
   let k = the count of r
   let prf, inf, suf = the prefix, infix and suffix of i according to r
   return cons (k+1) inf (insert prf lt) (insert suf rt)
```

Once the tree is built, we do a pre-order traversal of the tree, using the count of the node to accelerate the computation of the nth element.

---

*Below is my previous answer.*

Here are the steps of my solution:

- you need to sort the interval list in increasing order on the lower bound of each interval
- you need a deque `dq` (or a list which will be reversed at some point) to store the intervals

here's the code:

```
let lower i = lower bound of interval i
let upper i = upper bound of i

let il = sort of interval list
i <- 0
j <- lower (head of il)
loop on il:
  i <- i + 1
  let h = the head of il
  let il = the tail of il
  if upper h > j then push h to dq
  if lower h > j then
            il <- concat dq and il
            j <- j + 1
            dq <- empty
            loop
  if i = k then return j
  loop
```

This algorithm works by simply iterating through the intervals, only taking in account the relevant intervals, and counting both the rank `i` of the element in the union, and the value `j` of that element. When the targeted rank `k` has been reached, the value is returned.

The complexity is roughly in O(k) + O(sort(l)).

Comment: I think you've basically managed to achieve my answer, the long way aroung :)

Answer (score 1):

if i have understood your question correctly, you want to find the kth largest element  in union of list of intervals.
If we assume that no of list = 2 the question is :
Find the kth smallest element in union of two sorted arrays (where an interval [2,5] is nothing but elements from 2 to 5 {2,3,4,5}) this sollution can be solved in **(n+m)log(n+m)**  time where (n and m are sizes of list) . where i and j are list iterators .

```
Maintaining the invariant
    i + j = k – 1,
If Bj-1 < Ai < Bj, then Ai must be the k-th smallest,
or else if Ai-1 < Bj < Ai, then Bj must be the k-th smallest.
```

For details [click here](http://www.leetcode.com/2011/01/find-k-th-smallest-element-in-union-of.html)

Now the problem is if you have no of lists=3 lists then

```
 Maintaining the invariant
        i + j+ x = k – 1,
         i + j=k-x-1
     The value k-x-1 can take y (size of third list, because x iterates from start point of list to end point) .
    problem of 3 lists size can be reduced to y*(problem of size 2 list). So complexity is `y*((n+m)log(n+m))`

    If Bj-1 < Ai < Bj, then Ai must be the k-th smallest,
    or else if Ai-1 < Bj < Ai, then Bj must be the k-th smallest.
```

So for problem of size n list the complexity is NP .

But yes we can do minor improvement if we know that k< sizeof(some lists) we can chop the  elements starting from k+1th element to end(from our search space ) in those list whose size is bigger than k (i think it doesnt help for large k).If there is any mistake please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain with an example:
Assume we are given these intervals [5,12],[3,9],[8,13].
The union of these intervals is:

```
number : 3 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8  8  8  9  9  9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13.
indices: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

The `lowest` will return 11 when 9 is passed an input.
The `highest` will return 14 when 9 is passed an input.

Lowest and highest function just check whether the x is present in that interval, if it is present then adds x-a(lower index of interval) to return value for that one particular interval. If an interval is completely smaller than x, then adds total number of elements in that interval to the return value.

The find function will return 9 when 13 is passed.
The find function will use the concept of binary search to find the kth smallest element. In the given range [0,N] (if range is not given we can find high range in O(n)) find the mid and calculate the lowest and highest for mid. If given k falls in between lowest and highest return mid else if k is less than or equal to lowest search in the lower half(0,mid-1) else search in the upper half(mid+1,high).

 If the number of intervals are n and the range is N, then the running time of this algorithm is n*log(N). we will find lowest and highest (which runs in O(n)) log(N) times.

```
//Function call will be `find(0,N,k,in)`

//Retrieves the no.of smaller elements than first x(excluding) in union
public static int lowest(List<List<Integer>> in, int x){
    int sum = 0;
    for(List<Integer> lst: in){
        if(x > lst.get(1)) 
            sum += lst.get(1) - lst.get(0)+1;
        else if((x >= lst.get(0) && x<lst.get(1)) || (x > lst.get(0) && x<=lst.get(1))){
                sum += x - lst.get(0);

         }
        }

    return sum;
}
//Retrieve the no.of smaller elements than last x(including) in union.
public static int highest(List<List<Integer>> in, int x){
    int sum = 0;
    for(List<Integer> lst: in){
        if(x > lst.get(1)) 
            sum += lst.get(1) - lst.get(0)+1;
        else if((x >= lst.get(0) && x<lst.get(1)) || (x > lst.get(0) && x<=lst.get(1))){
                sum += x - lst.get(0)+1;

        }
        }
    return sum;
}

//Do binary search on the range.
public static int find(int low, int high, int k,List<List<Integer>> in){
    if(low > high)
        return -1;
    int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
    int lowIdx = lowest(in,mid);
    int highIdx = highest(in,mid);
    //k lies between the current numbers high and low indices
    if(k > lowIdx && k <= highIdx) return mid;
    //k less than lower index. go on to left side
    if(k <= lowIdx) return find(low,mid-1,k,in);
    // k greater than higher index go to right
    if(k > highIdx) return find(mid+1,high,k,in);
    else
        return -1; // catch statement
}
```

Comment: Add explanation to your answer

Comment: let me know if you didn't understand the solution now. I will try to be even more clear with my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to count how many numbers in the list are less than some chosen number X (by iterating through all of the intervals). Now, if this number is greater than n, the solution is certainly smaller than X. Similarly, if this number is less than or equal to n, the solution is greater than or equal to X. Based on these observation we can use binary search.

Below is a Java implementation :

```
public int nthElement( int[] lowerBound, int[] upperBound, int n )
   {
      int lo = Integer.MIN_VALUE, hi = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      while ( lo < hi ) {
         int X = (int)( ((long)lo+hi+1)/2 );
         long count = 0;
         for ( int i=0; i<lowerBound.length; ++i ) {
            if ( X >= lowerBound[i] && X <= upperBound[i] ) {
               // part of interval i is less than X
               count += (long)X - lowerBound[i];
            }
            if ( X >= lowerBound[i] && X > upperBound[i] ) {
               // all numbers in interval i are less than X
               count += (long)upperBound[i] - lowerBound[i] + 1;
            }
         }

         if ( count <= n ) lo = X;
         else hi = X-1;
      }

      return lo;
   }
```